# Fatal error on only some of my category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, category, error, collection

I updated yesterday to 1.9 CE and now my category pages I get this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::joinUrlRewrite() in /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php on line 155

This is the section it is referring to

```
public function getCurrentChildCategories()
   {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image') 
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
line 155        ->joinUrlRewrite()
            ->load();

        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($collection);
        return $collection;
    }
```

I have tried reindexing the URL, flushing my `mage_core_url_rewrite` then reindexing. But nothing had worked so far.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Just a prompt idea: did you reindex all your data after the update?

Comment: yea and everything was working fine until about an hour ago

Comment: Ensure you have no duplicate url_keys, you can use this query to check.
`SELECT url_key, COUNT(url_key) AS NumOccurrences FROM catalog_product_flat_1 GROUP BY url_key HAVING ( COUNT(url_key) > 1 );`

And make sure you read the [upgrade docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, for some reason when I disabled the flat catalog product and flat catalog category. The problem went away. I don't understand the fix but it worked.

Comment: If your store has many products, it's a good practice to keep flat category enabled.

Comment: I see the said a lot of places but why is that?

Comment: In my case it looks like to be a reindexing problem while we have many API requests. We are trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed `->joinUrlRewrite()` into `->addUrlRewriteToResult()`. This has worked for me.

Comment: Any idea why that worked? I see the difference between the two function. Is the category flat still working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange answer, but try checking your cpu load. I had a problem like this when cleanned the entire cache of a store.

It took some hours to get back to normal with no changes in config or code.